# How do I create header for rows/columns in a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 4 x 4 matrix and I want to make headers for its row and columns.

```
  1    2    3    4     
1 *    *    *    *
2 *    *    *    *
3 *    *    *    *
4 *    *    *    *
```

header for columns: print('    1 ','  2  ',' 3 ','  4 ') This works

header for rows:  print('1', '\n', '2','\n', '3', '\n', '4') This doesn't work

How do I do?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you need, but you can use column names with an array of values with `pandas` library.

Comment: Do you really want to print stars or the contents of a 4x4 matrix? And what exactly do you mean by "matrix" since that concept does not exist in Python proper--a list of lists, a `matrix` from numpy, a `ndarray` of shape `(4, 4)` from numpy, or something else?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I have already printed the "matrix", or rather a list of lists. But I want a user to select a "cell" within the "matrix", and thought it would look nicer if the rows/columns were numbered .

Comment: You seem to misunderstand my purpose. If you are just printing the stars, the job is much easier because each item is then just one character long and the columns easily become a straight line. If you are printing more general items, each item may have a different number of characters so lining them up in columns is more difficult. Pandas does the lining-up automatically, but if you do your own printing you will need to decide how to arrange the columns. Showing us a realistic example input and desired output would help us know what you need.

Comment: @RoryDaulton  Each item has the same number of characters. I am not allowed to use numpy or panda, if I could I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother doing these useless `print` statements, just use super quick and beautiful [**`pandas`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

(an example having  `*` as values):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame('*',index=range(1,5),columns=range(1,5))
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
   1  2  3  4
1  *  *  *  *
2  *  *  *  *
3  *  *  *  *
4  *  *  *  *
```

If you clicked on the blue **`pandas`** text, you we'll learn about pandas, pandas is not only displaying, you can do anything with data, (not the display, the actual data).

and if you really have to do `print` statement:

```
print('  1',' 2',' 3',' 4')
print('1 *  *  *  *\n2 *  *  *  *\n3 *  *  *  *\n4 *  *  *  *')
```

Output:

```
  1  2  3  4
1 *  *  *  *
2 *  *  *  *
3 *  *  *  *
4 *  *  *  *
```

Comment: `pandas` is not a thing, it's a python library (well it's not a book store library :-), but in python, library means a big thing that's importable :D), also, if you remove the for loop matrix, and just do my thing, will it work?

Comment: I will take a look on the panda thing. I tested the print method, and I got the same output. however I have a 4x4 matrix created by a for loop with '*', and the matrix doesn't get printed within the headers.

Comment: @Whatev Thanks, remember that you have to install pandas, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html